# PHP include help

Tags: php

Why does this work:

```
<?php include "includes/top_nav.php"; ?>
```

and why does this not work for me?

```
<?php include "http://localhost/includes/top_nav.php"; ?>
```

Comment: You forgot to add the error message.

Comment: There is no error message, the first example includes the html i expect it to include, and the second example does not include the html i expect it to include.

Comment: @oshiro there is bound to be an error message if you turn on error reporting: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: There isn't bound to be an error message; the file may get included just fine, but because it's now a separate HTTP request all bets are off as to what `top_nav.php` will actually do. Details in my answer below.

Comment: @Votey it's always bound to be an error message. Learn to use error messages properly

Comment: Of course there isn't always an error message. If all bad program behavior corresponded to error messages, programming would be easy. What I described is a case where all components of the program work as written and no detectable error has occurred, but where the environment is different from what the programmer expected.

Comment: @VoteyDisciple here it will be. You'd better learn error messages than playing fool here.

Comment: That still makes no sense. I obviously recommended looking at the error message as the most likely cause and then expanded with the next most likely scenario. Is your point that we shouldn't include additional information, or did you have a specific concern with what I described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two likely reasons.

First, your server may not be configured to allow URL file access. The error in that case would read, "URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration"

If the include actually works, but doesn't include what you expect, though, that's a whole other story. In that case, the key to understand is how such a request gets processed. While executing the script you shared, your server will perform an HTTP request (to itself) and ask for the output of `top_nav.php`. This is an entirely new request to the server, so the details about the ***original*** request are no longer in play.

The request will be coming from a different user (i.e., Apache) at a different IP address (i.e., your server's address, as opposed to the original client's), with different cookies, with different `$_GET` data and no `$_POST` data.

Thus, if `top_nav.php` in any way examines server variables, environment variables, PHP variables, or any other runtime state when rendering, this will fail.

Answer (score 5):

URL fopen wrappers is probably disabled on that server

http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable [URL fopen wrappers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) as said [in the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), and even if it's enabled, it doesn't work with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[From PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

> If "URL fopen wrappers" are enabled in
> PHP (which they are in the default
> configuration), you can specify the
> file to be included using a URL (via
> HTTP or other supported wrapper - see
> List of Supported Protocols/Wrappers
> for a list of protocols) instead of a
> local pathname.

What is the value of URL fopen wrappers on your server?